# Trying to add a new element to array of objects but after successfully pushing 1st object in Array(users). it rewrites it again

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a array of objects(users) where 2 elements in array are already hardcoded.While inserting new elements in array it overwrites the same element again & again.
I am trying to get new elements in my array every time I click Submit button.

Here is my code:

File **users.component.ts**

```
import { User } from './../Model/user';
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { getMaxListeners } from 'process';

@Component({
  selector: "app-users",
  templateUrl: "./users.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./users.component.css"],
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users?: User[] = [
    {
      name: "test1",
      email: "test@gmail.com",
    },
    {
      name: "test2",
      email: "test2@gmail.com",
    }
  ];
  addUserData: User = { name: null, email: null };
  bannerMsg: string = null;
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  addUser(addUserData) {
     this.users.push(addUserData);
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    console.log(
      "user data :" + this.addUserData.name + " " + this.addUserData.email
    );
    this.addUser(this.addUserData);
    this.users.forEach(item => {
      console.log("\n userObject"+ " "+ item.name+ "" + item.email);
    });

  }

}
```

File **users.component.html**

```
<form  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit('usersForm')" class="form-group"  class="solidBorderWithPadding" class="container" >
  <div>
    <label for="firstName">First Name </label>
    <input required minlength="3" [(ngModel)]="addUserData.name" name="firstName"   type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" class='form-control'>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="email">Email </label>
  <input required minlength="3" [(ngModel)]="addUserData.email" name="email"   type="email"  id="email" class="form-control" class='form-control'>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)='onSubmit()'>Submit</button>
</form>

<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let user of users">
  Name :  {{ user.name }}
  Email : {{ user.email}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You really want to rethink this approach. Everything is by reference with the way you set this up, so the behavior is expected. Loose the ngModel approach and go for a reactive form. Also, read up on immutability- it will make your code much more predictable- especially when it grows larger.

Answer (score 0):

Calling push will not copy your object, because JavaScript Objects are passed by reference: you're pushing the same Object as the array entry.

You can fix this easily by creating a new addUserDataObject every time you try to push one into the array.

Comment: That will probably not fix it.. there is 2-way binding with NgModel Pointing to that same object..

Comment: True. But he could clone the obj and push the cloned one, if he wanted to stick to his original aproach.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a clone of the User object solves this problem

```
addUser(addUserData) {
    var newobj = Object.assign({}, addUserData); //new code
     this.users.push(newobj);
  }
```